# How do I delete songs not in playlists in iTunes?

Tags: macos, itunes, music, xml, playlists

I have lots of music in iTunes, but there's tons of crap I never listen to just taking up space. Is there a way I can easily delete all songs *not* in a playlist?

**All the music I have put into playlists I would like to keep, but everything else I want to get rid of.**

Is there any way to do this at all? I would be happier to write some sort of script to do it than manually filter through over 1.2k songs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could add each playlist manually to a smart playlist like this:

[image]

Then delete the tracks on the smart playlist.

Answer (score 0):

Just select all songs/albums/playlists you want to keep, show details (edit all) and change the input under 'grouping' into, for example, 'cleaning up'. This way, all the music you want to keep is tagged. Now add 'grouping' to your sort bar (next to songs, artist, year etc) and you should be able to easily select all music you want to delete. You can loose the grouping tag afterwards if you want to.

Comment: Where are the "Show Detail" and "Edit all" options? I can't select multiple playlists (Shift + left-click isn't working). Also I can't seem to be able to change the grouping for multiple files (seems to only be possible through the Song Info dialog which opens per song.